# AudioBufferList Increase in Memory Usage

Tags: ios, c, memory-management, malloc, core-audio

I have the following code in a loop (it gets called every 1/4 second).
(I have removed the rest of the code to narrow the problem down to the following).

```
dispatch_async(self.audioQueue, ^{

        AudioBufferList *aacBufferList;

        aacBufferList = malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList));
        aacBufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
        aacBufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = aacStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
        aacBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize   = maxOutputPacketSize;
        aacBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData           = (void *)(calloc(maxOutputPacketSize, 1));

        // Other code was here. As stated above, I have removed it to isolate the problem to the allocating and freeing of memory for the AudioBufferList

        freeABL(aacBufferList);
}
```

And the freeABL function:

```
void freeABL(AudioBufferList *abl)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < abl->mNumberBuffers; i++)
    {
        free(abl->mBuffers[i].mData);
        abl->mBuffers[i].mData = NULL;
    }
    free(abl);
    abl = NULL;
}
```

The problem I have, is every time this loops the memory consumption of my app increased, until I receive a memory warning.

[image: Instruments showing __NSMallocBlock__ Increasing in size]

Comment: @NishithJainMR I hardly see how that helps. If you don't have any information that may help solve my problem, then please don't comment.

Comment: I suspect this is under XCode. Do you have any memory debuggers available to you under the IDE that would help diagnose the leak?

Comment: I have used instruments, it doesn't show any leaks but it does show that __NSMallocBlock__ keeps increasing by roughly 0.1MB every second.

Comment: You do not need to do:  `abl = NULL;` after free().  Besides that, the code you have mentioned is fine. The problem must be occurring somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanks @askmish. I believe I have narrowed it down to me having this code being called by another background thread (nested threads?) and I'm wondering if I ended up getting myself into some kind of deadlock/race condition. Anyway, I removed the dispatch_asynch from the code and it fixed the memory issues.